# Passing parameter depending on the flavor in build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I need to run a script before the build of my Android project. However, I want to pass a parameter to the script which depends on the variant being built (let's say the package name of the flavor). I know how to run the script for all variants, but I actually want to run it only for the current variant because it would take too much time otherwise.

My current build.gradle looks like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.3'

    productFlavors {
        MyFlavor {
            packageName "com.my.package"
        }
    }
}

task runScript(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'ruby', 'script.rb', my-package-name
}

preBuild.dependsOn runScript
```

Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom parameter property like below in build.gradle file:

```
packageName = hasProperty('packagename') ? packagename : 'your-default-package name'
```

Modify the line below in your build.gradle file:

```
task preBuild (type: Test, dependsOn: runScript)
```

And when you are running graldew from commandline, run something similar as below:

```
gradlew preBuild -Ppackagename="your-package-name"
```

Please let us know if that had worked!